# CPU clocks locking at max speed on Windows 10 even when it's not under load

Tags: windows-10, asus-laptop, intel-core-i7, cpu-speed

I have an Asus X510UR Laptop running a dual boot setup with Windows 10 (build 19042) and Ubuntu 20.04. Whenever I boot Windows and login, my CPU (an Intel i7 8550U) clock locks at max speed, temps rise up to 98C and fans start getting really loud.

I've checked my CPU temps and clocks on Ubuntu and they seem fine (40C/800MHz at idle), which leads me to believe that this is a problem related to Windows. I've also noticed that whenever I boot up unplugged, clock speeds stay at 399MHz, sometimes going up to 3.9GHz then immediately down again (it doesn't seem to vary a lot, it's always either at 399MHz or 3.9-ish GHz) and the computer gets painfully slow (this doesn't happen on Ubuntu though).

It might be worth mentioning that the battery is a little banged up as well. This laptop doesn't run more than 3 hours unplugged (even less on Windows because of the CPU clock speeds).

The problem here is that the fan noise gets pretty annoying over time and I'd like to bring it down, but the CPU doesn't seem to be very happy running at lower clocks. Can someone help me?

Comment: The issue you describe is likely caused by your battery

Comment: @Ramhound But how would it be?

Comment: How would what be?  Your problem is likely connected to the bad battery